# WebView не видит авторизацию vk sdk

Tags: android-studio, android-vksdk, android-webview

Доброго времени суток. В android studio сделал приложение. Запилил авторизацию vk sdk. На активити добавил webview и кнопку. Авторизация вк проходит нормально. В webview открываю сайт, на нем нужно авторизоваться через вк. Проблема в том, что сайт в webview не видит, что я уже авторизован в вк. Как решить эту проблему? Спасибо.

Comment: По идее, авторизовавшись в ВК через SDK вы получаете `token`. Не известно что у вас там на сайте, но он точно не может автоматически этот токен сам получить. Вам надо его как-то на сайт передать. Как именно - зависит от сайта. Возможно надо просто ко всем запросам прикреплять.

Comment: Можите на каком-нибудь примере показать как передавать\прикреплять к запросам token? Спасибо.

Comment: Я сам ни разу не пробовал и это может зависеть от реализации сайта, но можете попробовать как параметр `url` передавать. Типа так: `http://site.ru?token=token_from_vk` но это точно надо сайт смотреть чтобы точно понять как нужно делать.

Comment: вот сайт https://topcraft.ru на нем хочу сделать автоматическую авторизацию через вк

Comment: Ну, там куки в заголовках передаются... Вам надо как-то их получить, сохранить и ко всем запросам через WebView прикреплять. Как - не знаю, я такого никогда не делал)

Comment: Спасибо за информацию!